# What is the expected effect of pH on the activity of a fungal pectinase?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, microbiology, enzymes, biotechnology

I am working on an enzyme assay for a fungal pectinase.I assayed the enzyme in different buffers from pH 1-12.5 However,the enzyme has good activities starting from pH1-10.5.

Is it possible to have enzyme activity over such a broad range of pH?

Comment: Can you tell us which pectinase you are using? Besides that, is the activity the same over this pH range or does it vary? Can you show a curve of the activity plotted against the pH?

Comment: Could you also give more details of methodology and controls - pectin can be hydrolysed non-enzymatically at low and high pH.

Answer (score 2):

I actually doubt that the pectinase has such a broad pH range in which it works optimally. Searching the web I found two figures which support my doubts:

[image]

[image]

The first is from an article ("[Immobilization of pectinase by adsorption on an alginate-coated chitin support](http://scielo.sld.cu/scielo.php?pid=S1027-28522013000200003&script=sci_arttext)") which compares the activity of native and immobilized pectinase under different conditions. The second is from the [datasheet](http://www.biovet.com/rus/pdfs/Pectinase.pdf) of a company which sells the enzyme. Both show an activity over 50% roughly between pH 3.5 and 5.5 but not at higher or lower pH values.

Comment: I extracted the enzyme from 48 hours actinomycete culture ( submerged fermentation) the methodology I used is miller DNSA method